# Can no longer ping router, 8.8.8.8 or gain internet access after removing Norton

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, ping

I'm at a total loss.

- removed Norton with their removal tool.
- lost all internet access
- did a `netsh int ip reset` still no internet and I cannot even ping my router or `8.8.8.8` - error message is `General failure`
- tried to type `ipconfig /flushdns` and still does not work.
- disable Windows firewall, still no good.

Can anyone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Try DISM / SFC :    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: have you tried using the network troubleshooter?

Comment: Did you gave/use Norton VPN until now? Can you check in Control Panel if there is still anything with the word Norton, Symantec, or VPN there? Did you restart the computer after running Norton removal tool? Can you try running the tool again?

Comment: @John thanks. step 1-2, and 4 completed however step 3 failed, source file could not be found. Anyways, ran step 4 and it was succesful, restarted computer. Same error ;(

Comment: @JaromandaX yes tried many times.

Comment: @YisroelTech no I did not not use norton vpn. checked control panel and there is no norton. however strangely windows security, under virus & threat it says action is needed for symentec end point.  I also tried removing again and restarted however still no internet ;(

Comment: There is also no Symantec (or anything 'endpoint') in control panel? Maybe try the CleanWipe as directed here https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/178870/download-the-cleanwipe-removal-tool-to-u.html

Comment: Norton likely modified your hosts file. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Ramhound it probably did since the last mod date and time corresponded to the event however that file is empty

Answer (score 1):

> (DISM / SFC) step 1-2, and 4 completed however step 3 failed, source
> file could not be found. Anyways, ran step 4 and it was successful,
> restarted computer. Same error.

This means more serious operating system errors and/or perhaps a Windows User Profile error.

Start with a Windows 10 Repair Install to see if that works.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to **Keep Everything.**

Try Keep Everything and test.

If that option does not work, then the damage is more serious.

In this event, back up everything and reinstall Windows.

Comment: thanks; tried it and try installing it however without connection it just goes into an endless loop; restarting every time I tell it to keep everything and move on. Any tips?

Comment: You probably at this point need to re-install Windows fresh. If Repair Keep Everything does not / cannot work, then you need to Reinstall Windows (my second point in my post).

Answer (score 0):

It's unknown what damage happened to Windows when you removed Norton.
It's perhaps best to use a heavy hammer and do a Repair Install.

This will require preparing on another computer a boot media for
Windows, or to download the latest Windows ISO, then executing
the `Setup.exe` file from inside Windows (because luckily you can
still boot Windows).

For a detailed description of the method see the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).